# Call from C# to C++ fails to pass parameters correctly

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have a very basic call from C# to C++. The function call takes three parameters:

```
extern "C" int CLIENT_API example(const char, char * const, const unsigned int);
```

The C# code imports that function as:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int example(in sbyte id, byte[] buffer, in uint bufferSize);
```

When I call the function from C# like this:

```
uint bufferSize = 400;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
example(0, buffer, bufferSize);
```

I log on the C++ size variant values for both id and bufferSize (every run has different values for those two variables). What am I doing wrong? I have other interop functions that pass pointers and strings to my C++ DLL and they aren't having any issues. It seems like it just happens with the more primitive types of byte and uint.

Comment: Do **not** use `in` in pinvoke declarations, it is pure C# hackorama to disguise a pointer.  Awful hack that came from the Roslyn team, battling compile perf moving from C++ to C#.  The values you see look random because the real value that's passed (the pointer) is unpredictable.  Just delete `in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` modifier makes the argument a read-only `ref` argument.  It's not the same as the `[In]` attribute, which is a marshalling hint.

You're passing `0` and `bufferSize`, and C# is taking their addresses (the literal `0` by way of a temporary variable) and passing those.

You're getting varying values because the address is different each time.

Remove the `in` modifiers so that C# passes those values rather than addresses.